# How do I optimize this logic about the if condition?

Tags: java, algorithm

This is some logic. Can I optimize this?

```
for (List<String> sublist: list){
    for (String string: sublist){
        if(condition1){
            if(condition2){
                if(!condition3){
                    c();
                    condition3 = true;
                }
            } else {
                c();
            }
        } else {
            Log();
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks. It has 3 conditions but I use function c() twice.
Finally, I found the best one:

```
for (List<String> sublist: list){
    for (String string: sublist){
        if(condition1){
            if(condition2){
                if(condition3) continue;
                condition3 = true;
            }
            c();
        } else {
            Log();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, this looks all right to me. But if you really wanted to flatten out that third `if` statement, you could do it like this:

```
if (condition1) {
    if (!condition2 || !condition3) {
        c();
    }
    if (condition2 && !condition3) {
        condition3 = true;
    }
} else {
    Log();
}
```

Comment: well. Many thanks. But condition3 = true; only when (condition2 && !condition3) is pass. Let me try.

Comment: Note that `if (condition2 && !condition3) { condition3 = true; }` can be simplified to `if (condition2) { condition3 = true; }`, since there's no harm in setting `condition3` to `true` if it's already `true`.

Comment: Thank you. Finally, I found the best one.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```cpp
for (List<String> sublist: list){
    for (String string: sublist){
        if (condition1) {
            if (contition2 && condition3) continue;
            condition3 |= condition2;
            c();
        } else {
            Log();
        }
    }
}
```

As I think, the variable `condition3` is considered only for `true`.

thus, I used bitwise operation for it.

Comment: Hehe, thank you very much. It's a good idea. I do not have enough 15 reputations to vote you guys help up. Sorry hehe.